# Define $-S = \{-x \mid x \in S\}$ , prove $\sup(-S) = -\inf(S)$ and $\inf(-S) = - \sup(S)$, with $S$ is bounded both sides

Tags: calculus

> Define $-S = \{-x \mid x \in S\}$
>
> Prove $\sup(-S) = -\inf(S)$ and $\inf(-S) = - \sup(S)$, with $S$ bounded both sides

Can someone help me with this, i dont get this type of more "complex" inf and sup excersises, detailed explanation would be appreciated, thanks alot !

Comment: I think that an example would be very enlightning. Suppose $S=[4,6]$. Then $-S=[-6, -4]$. So maximum becomes (-minimum), and the minimum becomes (-maximum). Can you see this? At the same time every upper bound becomes a lower bound and viceversa.

Comment: Can you first recall what definition you use for $\sup$ and $\inf$. Just recalling the definition will probably bring you on the track.

Comment: Thank you very much ! It's very easy, i feel stupid now :)

Comment: Please search before asking. There's a bazillion questions about similar problem on this site, for example [Supremum and Infimum](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/14977).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With S bounded both sides and not empty the assertion is true. For let sup S=a and inf S=b. Now the set -S is bounded above by -b. If we take any positive e and form -b-e =-(b+e) then we know that there is an s in S trapped between b and b+e ( from def of sup S) and so -s is trapped between -b and -b-e. We see that -b is a sup for -S. Thus sup(-S)=-inf S. Thus -inf(-S)=sup (S) and so inf(-S)=-sup S